# no adb devices detected after failed revert to Android

Tags: adb, installation, nexus-7

Just a few days ago I tried to revert my Asus Nexus 7 wifi back to Android from Ubuntu Touch Preview and made a mistake somewhere. To sum up, now my device has no OS on it so it will only show the bootloader, and it does not show up as an adb device but still shows on fastboot. Here's a summary

1. Downloaded Android 4.2.2 nakasi via https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasi
2. followed instructions from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation#Returning_your_Nexus_7_to_Stock_Android
3. failed on step "writing 'radio'". Also got: archive does not contain 'boot.sig', archive does not contain 'recovery.sig', archive does not contain 'system.sig'
4. tried multiple times with the same errors.
5. got frustrated and restarted to try again
6. now I have a blank list of adb devices

Anyone have advice on where I can learn to fix this or want to help with some suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't worry. Adb requires an installed Android or an Android recovery. You just need to flash a recovery manually and then boot this to have adb again...

Answer (score 1):

Just did all the necessary steps on my N7:

- Download the factory image from [Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasijdq39)
- Unpack the downloaded file (e.g. by `tar -xvzf nakasi-jdq39-factory-c317339e.tgz`)
- Boot your N7 into the bootloader (hold the power and both volume buttons)
- Have fastboot installed (comes with the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) or for Ubuntu, just install [android-tools-fastboot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/raring/android-tools-fastboot))
- connect it to your machine
- Flash it using *flash-all.bat* or *flash-all.sh* (needs installed fastboot)

Here's the transcript (using Ubuntu):

```
me@localhost:/tmp/nakasi-jdq39$ ls
bootloader-grouper-4.18.img  flash-all.sh   image-nakasi-jdq39.zip
flash-all.bat                flash-base.sh
me@localhost:/tmp/nakasi-jdq39$ bash flash-all.sh 
...
(bootloader) Bootloader is already unlocked
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
erasing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.104s]
finished. total time: 0.104s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.147s]
finished. total time: 0.147s
erasing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.106s]
finished. total time: 0.106s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.175s]
finished. total time: 0.175s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  1.401s]
finished. total time: 1.401s
sending 'bootloader' (2096 KB)...
OKAY [  0.286s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  1.165s]
finished. total time: 1.452s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: 4.18
Baseband Version.....: N/A
Serial Number........: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.040s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.023s]
sending 'boot' (4944 KB)...
OKAY [  0.654s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.172s]
sending 'recovery' (5446 KB)...
OKAY [  0.712s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.193s]
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.055s]
sending 'system' (471804 KB)...
OKAY [ 60.282s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 23.357s]
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  1.023s]
formatting 'userdata' partition...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 14442037248
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8176
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label: 
    Blocks: 3525888
    Block groups: 108
    Reserved block group size: 863
Created filesystem with 11/883008 inodes and 96825/3525888 blocks
sending 'userdata' (137526 KB)...
writing 'userdata'...
OKAY [ 27.078s]
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.050s]
formatting 'cache' partition...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 464519168
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7088
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1772
    Label: 
    Blocks: 113408
    Block groups: 4
    Reserved block group size: 31
Created filesystem with 11/28352 inodes and 3654/113408 blocks
sending 'cache' (9052 KB)...
writing 'cache'...
OKAY [  1.751s]
rebooting...

finished. total time: 115.545s
```

Comment: I attempted what you suggested and simply get '...' indefinitely. There was a comment I saw on my original post yesterday that a link that looked promising, but I didn't have time to look at it then and now it seems to have been removed.

Comment: After several attempts and many errors this finally worked! Thanks all!

Comment: FYI: Good that you chose a Nexus. The Nexus line is almost unbrickable by fiddling with custom firmware such as CyanogenMod, Ubuntu Touch or Firefox OS,... PS: Would you mind to 'upvote' my answer?